# How to connect date table (date type column) to fact table date (datetime type column) type?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

My date table dimension has date of date type.

Sales fact table has date of type datetime.

In model, how to connect date table (date type column) to fact table date (datetime column) type?

Comment: Add a Date column to your fact table.

Comment: Do you mean duplicate the existing fact table date and change it to date type?

Comment: This is one way to do it.

Comment: Any other way please.

Comment: Add [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question and you will get more meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your data model is broken. If you want to join to a Date Dimension then you need to add a column with a Date datatype to your fact table - whether you just add the date column or also drop the timestamp column is up to you and your specific requirements.

If you also need to join to a time dimension then you'll need to add a column to your fact table that has the same datatype as the PK on your Time Dim